# Meaning of "Stories, that is, of human authorship"

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, commas

Do these following sentences have the same meaning?

> 1. In songs and stories, that is, of human authorship.
> 2. In songs and stories, that is of human authorship.

Context:

What is half-seen in this manner is quite often a specimen of the species homo sapiens, and from such half-glances may derive that "knowledge of human nature" for which human beings are famous in song and story. In songs and stories, that is, of human authorship.

Comment: Those are not "sentences" in the ordinary use of that term.

Comment: What is half-seen in this manner is quite often a specimen of the species homo sapiens, and from such half-glances may derive that "knowledge of human nature" for which human beings are famous in song and story. In songs and stories, that is, of human authorship. Does it make sense that way? @StoneyB

Comment: @Sto How about in the sense that they normally start with capital letters and end with terminal punctuation? That's one "serious" definition.

Comment: @JimReynolds I entirely agree--in fact, that is to my mind the *only* useful definition of *sentence*. Alas, it is not the ordinary use in the teaching of English, so I felt a warning was in order.

Comment: @Well nevertheless, I adamantly maintain that . . . What?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correctly punctuated to set off *that is* as discourse-marking text.

The writer is using *that is* to imply that what's been said before applies to the specified type of songs and stories: Those produced by people.

The second sentence is ungrammatical.

The writer seems to be saying something similar to:

What humans understand about ourselves comes from our own ideas about ourselves. There might be other perspectives in observations about humans made by non-humans (maybe by animals, nature, or some other real or abstract observer or intelligence).

Comment: So, just to know: I found an example in the Cambridge Dictionary, "The article is of unknown authorship" with the explanation "it is not known who wrote it", then what is the difference b/w two structures or what does the comma stand for? @jim-reynolds

Comment: We can write: *In songs and stories that ARE of human authorship.* With no comma. The difference is that with commas, the writer may be more strongly suggesting that there might be other kinds of songs and stories, or that non-human songs or stories may reflect quite different ideas about human nature.

Comment: *Stories of human authorship* means stories made (written, invented) by humans. If you still have a question, please keep asking.